# Approve BNB spend

Tags: binance-smart-chain

This is not ERC20 related, rather for BSC. Before a pre-sale, I want to manually approve a contract allowing the site to spend my BNB. I've seen how this can be done from bscscan.com (contract -> write -> approve), but BNB doesn't have a contract, so I'm not sure how to do this. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: BNB is the native currency of BSC. That cannot be done for the native currency without writing a smart contract. Maybe there is WBNB which is the Token equivalent of BNB

Answer (score 1):

You can't approve BNB because it's not an BEP20 so it don't have it smart contract, you need to transfer it while using msg.value.

As said previously, if the pre-sale you want to join accept the WBNB (BNB token wrapped as BEP20), you can approve it.